# How to Assign an array value to session variable in zend framework

Tags: php, arrays, session, zend-framework

I am trying to create a session variable and assign values in an array to this session variable. how can i do that.
i am creating like below but i cannot get to it is functioning at all.

```
$post = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('key');
$searches = new Zend_Session_Namespace('searches');
$parthis= $searches->partssearched;
if(!is_array($parthis)){
    $parthis->toArray();
    $parthis[0]=$post;
} else {

$count= sizeof($parthis)."<br>";
if ($this->rows ) {
    if ($count==0) {$parthis[0]=$post;}
    //$searches[$count]=$this->rows;
    echo $parthis[0]."HERE";
} else {
    $parthis[$count]=$post;
    foreach($parthis as $hist) {
        echo $hist;
    }

}
}
```

`$this->rows` are coming from the controller and it is carrying database query results.

What i am trying to do here is i want to store the Get value into a session variable carrying it as an array.

Should be like `$parthis= array (value1, value2, value3);`
and every time user pass a value in url, it should add upto it.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you expect the line with `$parthis->toArray()` to do? You aren't assigning the value to anything

Comment: i see, please see the edit i just made. i am really new to this.

Comment: Again, `$parthis->toArray()` does **nothing** on its own. You will need to assign it to something, eg `$parthisArray = $parthis->toArray()`

Comment: i am adding a value to it as $parthis[0]=$post; i am  unable to understand itwhether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

```
$this->objSess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('searches');

$details[$ItemID]=array(
    'itmeid'=>$ItemID,
    'itemname'=>$itemname['ItemName'],
    'qty'=>$Quantity,
    'price'=>$Price,
    'originalprice'=>$itemname['OriginalPrice'],
    'saveprice'=>number_format($itemname['OriginalPrice']*$Quantity,2),
        'restaurantid'=>$RestaurantID,
    'Conversionsymbol'=>$conversionsymbol,
    'ConversionRate'=>$currencyrate,
    );

$this->objSess->ORDERITEMS=$details;
```

or you can also use alternate way

```
$this->objSess->ORDERITEMS[$ItemID]['qty']=$details[$ItemID]['qty'];
$this->objSess->ORDERITEMS[$ItemID]['price']=$details[$ItemID]['price'];
```

hope this will sure help you

Comment: @Justin,pls dont forget to acpt.if i could help u.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this.

```
$key = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('key');
$searches = new Zend_Session_Namespace('searches');
if (!is_array($searches->partssearched)) {
    $searches->partssearched = array($key);
} else {
    array_push($searches->partssearched, $key);
}
```

this will create and update your array, you can view it by `print_r($searches->partssearched);`

If you are writing this with in an action you can use this instead of the 1st line.

```
$key = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```